# Como alterar outro elemento com CSS puro?

Tags: css, css-seletores

Como consigo alterar um outro element com CSS Puro, a partir de um elemento?

Tentei fazer isso mas não rolou. Não conheço a fundo os seletores e maravilhas do CSS.

```css
input {
  display: block;
  transition: top .3s, left .3s;
}
label {
  position: relative;
  top: 17px;
  font-size: 12px;
  left: 5px;
}
input:focus ~ label {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<label>Label</label>
<input type="text">
```

O que quero fazer é ao focar no input, subir o label com CSS puro.

Comment: O label é pra ficar dentro do input mesmo?

Comment: Quero fazer a mesma coisa do Materialize, quando clicar no input o label volta para sua posição inicial. So que preciso  no focus do input, alterar a posição do label e não sei se é possível fazer isso com CSS puro, essa é minha esperança. Abs

Comment: Beleza. Acho que seria importante ter essa descrição na pergunta.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}
input {
  display: block;
  transition: top .3s, left .3s;
  position: relative;
  top: 17px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
label {
  transition: .2s linear;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  left: 5px;
}
input:focus + label {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text">
  <label>Label</label>
</div>
```

Basicamente peguei seu input e label adicionei dentro de uma div e troquei de posição, o seletor "+" significa que sera pego o elemento imediatamente precedido, no caso "input:focus + label", quando o input estiver focado ele pegara o próximo elemento label, troquei alguns posicionamentos do seu css e adicionei o "transition: .2s linear;", ele sera responsável pela animação suave do texto subindo.
O seletor "~" também iria funcionar, mais no caso, todas as label para baixo também aplicaria o efeito.

Comment: Perfeito cara, era exatamente isso que queria! Obrigado e bem vindo!

Comment: Eu que agradeço!

Comment: @VictorPereira gostei demais do exemplo, se explicar tem o meu +1

Comment: Explicado, espero ter ajudado!